# ExpressJS routes not resolving

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have a small microservice written in typescript running in a kubernetes cluster on AKS.
I have ingress generated using Helm

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-service
  labels:
    app: test-service
    chart: test-service-0.1.0
    release: test-service
    heritage: Tiller
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.xyz
      secretName: default-tls
  rules:
    - host: test.xyz
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /payments
            backend:
              serviceName: test-service
              servicePort: 4040
```

And the service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: existing-bumblebee-payments-service
  labels:
    app: test-service
    chart: test-service-0.1.0
    release: existing-bumblebee
    heritage: Tiller
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 4040
      targetPort: 4040
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: test-service
    release: existing-bumblebee
```

And in my microservice

```
export class Server {
private registerRoutes() {
        this.app.use("/cards", CardRouter);
        this.app.use("/wallets", WalletRouter);
        this.app.use("/preauth", PreauthRouter);
        this.app.use("/charge", ChargeRouter);
    }
}
```

The routers look like this;

```
    import { Router } from "express";
    // other imports
    import { checkSchema, check } from "express-validator/check";

    const router = Router();

    router.get("/", CardController.index);
    router.get("/:id", [
        check("id")
            .isUUID()
            .withMessage("Invalid UUID")
    ], CardController.get);
    router.delete("/:id", [
        check("id")
            .isUUID()
            .withMessage("Invalid UUID")
    ], CardController.remove);
    router.post("/", checkSchema(CardCreateRules), CardController.add);

export default router;
```

But accessing the service via `https://test.xyz/payments/cards` results in a 404 error from express

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /payments/cards</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can tell the response is from the express server cause it has custom response headers set by the server.
I'm really confused as to what is wrong, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is not really enough info here to bottom out the problem. Is the IP in DNS for https://test.xyz definitely the IP of the nginx ingress you have created and not still pointing at a default ingress?

Comment: @SimonMcClive Yes, it is. The IP is provisioned by Azure AKS.

Comment: do you have your Service definition / NodePort definition yaml you could share.

Comment: @SimonMcClive I have update the post with the service definition

Comment: What do your Routers look like? Can you provide an example of one?

Comment: @Brandon I've added a sample router

Comment: Have you tried just specifying an empty path for routes that terminate at their root? Like: `router.get("", CardController.index);` ?

Comment: @Brandon No, i haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work for you because your ingress just redirects request https://test.xyz/payments/cards to test-service **without rewriting the path**. So test service still becomes request "/payments/cards" and obviously can not handle them.

You can either reconfigure express application to support /payments/cards or do the path rewrite via ingess 'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target' annotation:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-service
  labels:
    app: test-service
    chart: test-service-0.1.0
    release: test-service
    heritage: Tiller
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /payments
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.xyz
      secretName: default-tls
  rules:
    - host: test.xyz
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: test-service
              servicePort: 4040
```

Comment: Oh wow, never knew about the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation. I'll give it a try